# How to get rid of the default x axis scale value in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, formatting, scale

I am populating x axis scale using an array with some nil values in it. Highcharts sets the nil values to their index value on the scale. I want to get rid of these default numbers on the x axis. Anybody knows how to do it?

Comment: Try to push empty string instead of nils. If you mean categories (as scale).

Comment: Thanks, was a quick fix!